# Is it safe to delete my index lock files?

Tags: indexing, reindex, ee-1.13

I am trying to reindex but I get an error "Stock Status Index process is working now. Please try run this process later.". When I look at `MAGENTO_ROOT/var/locks` I see a ton of lock files.  Some are like "index_process_7.lock" but others are like "index_process_7e7e2219-ceb3-11e5-b966-d4ae52e7d176.lock".

None of them have been modified since 2016. Is it safe to just delete them?

Comment: Yes, it is safe to delete them, but you should also check if those processes are still running and try to figure out what is causing it to stop.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure for E.E. but as of version CE 1.9 Magento does no longer use these lock files by default. So yeah, it is safe to delete them.

The indexer status is now stored in the database in the index_process table.